# Fortran mpi runtime error

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to understand parallel data writing from Fortran code with MPI. I came across a simple program from [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/usingmpi2/examples/starting/io3f_f90.htm).

I compiled and run the program with MPI compiler and getting the following error:

```
sathish@HP-EliteBook:~/Desktop$ mpif90 test.F90 -o test
sathish@HP-EliteBook:~/Desktop$ mpirun -np 4 test
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I see similar issues in other forums mentioning this is due to wrong mpi installation location or so. The following was one of the solutions suggesting use of `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
sathish@HP-EliteBook:~/Desktop$ mpirun -x LD_PRELOAD=libmpi.so -np 4 test
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
```

The issue still persists. I could not figure what the issue is for such a simple program.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but `test` might be one of the worse name you can give for a binary you compiled, since it is also the name of a command from the shell. Furthermore, since you didn't use any path to access it (like `./test` for example) it is really unclear which of the shell command or the binary is called (I'd go for the shell one but I'm not positive on it). Anyway, try renaming your binary into something more sensible and try again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:
run as

```
mpirun -np 4 ./test
```

instead of:

```
mpirun -np 4 test
```

Details:
That is a common problem that happens when your working directory is not in your path. The simple solution is to add the full path to the executable. Another alternative might be to add the current directory to your `path` variable. However, in this case, even if you add the current directory to the path, the order will matter. Linux systems (it seems to be your case) usually come with a program named `test` that is usually in the `path` by default.

What is going on is that you do not start mpi program directly, instead, you start `mpirun` that will start the `mpi` machinery, and start your program that will make use of that machinery. `mpirun` has to find your program. And there is where comes the two options I suggested above: full path to your executable or add your directory to your search `path`.